# Making Slides + also Handouts with notes?

Tags: beamer

I have a following minimal example for beamer (latex) presentation.

I need some handouts, very importantly, with my own notes, important things to say, just right hand side of the smaller slides. 2 or 3 slides with notes per each A4 page.

From a single document with some little changes, Is there some possible macros so that I can hide my notes for making regular slides, and tell pdflatex to make a beamer class presentation (very normal, landscape) and also a handdout class document (a4 portrait) with all what I have to say? 
Pdflatex would then create a regular pdf with the slides, but also another pdf with the handouts. This is very much what can do all Powerpoint versions from Microsoft, since 1995 or even earlier.

I was thinking that it could be done with some usepackage pdfpages, to nup a sort of thumbnails, and then to add some minipage to bring the important messages. Well, this much too complicated.

Maybe you would find a better idea!

I need as fast as possible. If you have any possible idea, please let me know. This may very much help!

thank you in advance a lot!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\title{Simple Beamer Class}   
\author{Sascha Frank} 
\date{\today} 

\frame{\titlepage} 
\frame{\frametitle{Table of contents}\tableofcontents} 
\section{Section no.1} 
\frame{\frametitle{Title} 
Each frame should have a title.
}
\subsection{Subsection no.1.1  }
\frame{ 
Without title somethink is missing. 
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the following example `\documentclass{beamer}` will create a regular presentation, `\documentclass[handout]{beamer}` the handout version with notes and 2x2 per page.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\mode<handout>{%
    \pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper] 
    \setbeameroption{show notes}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    content for the presentation
    \note{your important notes}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    another frame
    \note{another note}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it is awesome. Would you know how to have it without grey background (on notes), but rather with a white background? In fact, I pay a lot of ink with grey color. ok, I got it with adding: \setbeamercolor{note page}{bg=white}

Comment: it is awesome.  I got it with adding: \setbeamercolor{note page}{bg=white}  Would you know how to remove the mini thumbnail and the section/... top bar, so that one can see only the notes. A bit like in Powerpoint.

Comment: @user98734 You can format the note page to whatever you like using `\setbeamertemplate{note page}{<whatever you want> \insertnote}`